# OpenLDAP error configuring StartTLS: ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)

Tags: openldap, tls

Configuring StartTLS for OpenLDAP.

- Ubuntu server 16.04
- Slapd 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.2

I have my own internal Certificate authority that is providing certificates.

I have set up certificates and key:
in /etc/ssl/certs:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root ssl-cert   3268 Jul 14 23:02 ldaptest.roenix.net.cert.pem

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         51 Jul  2 13:22 roenix.ca.cert.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/roenix.ca.cert.crt
```

in /etc/ssl/private:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root ssl-cert 3243 Jul 14 23:01 ldaptest.roenix.net.key.pem
```

I have correctly set hostname:

```
@ldaptest:/etc/ssl/certs$ hostname -f
ldaptest.roenix.net
```

I try to add the configuration to slapd with this LDIF:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/roenix.ca.cert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldaptest.roenix.net.cert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldaptest.roenix.net.key.pem
```

With the command:

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f certinfo.ldif
```

I get this error:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Normally `slapd` runs as user `openldap`. You should give read access to this user for the TLS files.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I failed to mention I made user openldap a member of the group open-ssl. Do you recommend a different method of giving access?

Comment: What are the access right on `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/roenix.ca.cert.crt`? And does the `openldap` user can change into `/etc/ssl/private`? Which manual did you follow?

Comment: Thomas you're an absolute hero! How could I miss the symlink... Changed the group on /usr/local/share/.... and it's fixed!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas' comment put me on the right track.

Cause of the problem:
I failed to realize that /etc/ssl/certs/roenix.ca.cert.crt is actually a symlink to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/roenix.ca.cert.crt.

Solution:
Set correct permissions on the actual cert file in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates.

Also read the other comments and learned a lot! Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by changing the order in the file.ldif like this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/your_key

dn: cn=config 
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile 
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/your_certificate
```

and the I ran the command

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f your_file.ldif
```

make sure that there an acl that makes the root eligible to make change with authenticating with SASL bind.

To make sure that changes have been done, run this command

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config | grep olcTLS
```

Comment: Swapping the order (key, then cert) did it! Thanks!

Comment: it does not for me !!!

Comment: Swapping the order (Key, then cert did it) Thaks

Comment: Swapping the order worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Certificates were stored in the `/opt/local/cert`.

You must add this directory to the list of the resolved files in `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.slapd`:

```
/opt/local/cert/ r,
/opt/local/cert/* r,
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can be also a permission error.
For example if did this command

```
vim newcerts.ldif

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/myca.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap1.mydom.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap1.mydom.key
-
replace: olcTLSRandFile
olcTLSRandFile: /dev/urandom
```

then

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f newcerts.ldif

SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

but after give with setfacl the permission of read keyfile to openldap user(the certs are usually 644 readable by all)

```
setfacl -m u:openldap:r-x /etc/ssl/private
setfacl -m u:openldap:r-x /etc/ssl/private/ldap1.mydom.key
```

all works

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f newcerts.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem just use in the correct order first key then cert. And it worked for me.

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/myldap.kart.com.key 

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/myldap.kart.com.cert
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem could also be that SELinux is preventing slapd from read access to the .key and .cert file. Please add policy for the files, dont turn SELinux off.

Having problem with SELinux. Use tool setroubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

To help others like me, this error can also be triggered if you have a key with a passphrase. This seems trivial, but easily forgotten. And of course, the error message doesn't help.

To remove the passphrase, you can use:

```
openssl rsa -in my.key -out my_no_password.key
```